# Invalid number of arguments in server name with the latest Docker image

Tags: nginx, processmaker

After I pull the latest available Process Maker image from DockerHub (`https://hub.docker.com/r/processmaker/processmaker` using `docker pull processmaker/processmaker` ) I get the following error:

% docker run processmaker/processmaker

`nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "server_name" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/processmaker.conf:6`

By definition I was expecting not to have to install or configure ProcessMaker outside of its container - but did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The processmaker/processmaker image requires the environment variable: URL. When you set -e URL=desiredHostname, it will update the nginx vhost configuration with the proper server_name. I'll reach out to have it updated so that it defaults to localhost when no URL environment variable is given.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check whether you end block declarations with ';'

I ran into a similar issue recently and adding the semicolon to declarations inside the blocks was all I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it did not work

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 processmaker/processmaker -e URL=localhost
```